# cocos2d orientation issues in ios<= 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I developed a game supports only landscape mode for upper than ios 4.3 devices.
the application has gamecenter implemented and crashed during the test on ios 6 devices because gamecenter login screen doesn't support landscape mode in ios 6.
so I fixed the problem adding below code into appdelegate.m and got worked but now application displays totally wired(displays portrait upside down) on devices below ios6(ios5 etc)

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else // iphone
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

use
xcode:4.5
cocos2d v1.0.1

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add given class in your project

```
GKMatchmakerViewController-LandscapeOnly.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@interface GKMatchmakerViewController(LandscapeOnly)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
@end

GKMatchmakerViewController-LandscapeOnly.m


#import "GKMatchmakerViewController-LandscapeOnly.h"

@implementation GKMatchmakerViewController (LandscapeOnly)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
}

@end
```

Comment: can you pls explain how does it work? do I need to call this class in appdelegate or rootviewcontroller?

Comment: you just create this file and call GKMatchmakerViewController in GCHelper class

Comment: if any problem tell me again

Comment: sorry for late reply.unfortunately couldn't solve the problem with this solution.however I was able to figure it out by changing codes related to orientation in the appdelegate.Thank you

Comment: ok, but i am using this code in current game and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line of code [window addSubview: viewController.view]; with below one in AppDelegate.m

```
//************************************************************************
    NSString *reqSysVer = @"6.0";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        [window setRootViewController:viewController];
    } else
    {
        [window addSubview: viewController.view];
    }
    //************************************************************************
```

And in RootViewController.m add below code

```
///////********************************/////////

// For ios6, use supportedInterfaceOrientations & shouldAutorotate instead of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

///////********************************/////////
```